# How to get DNS records for my Heroku site to play nice with Google Apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns

My website is hosted on Heroku and the domain with Namecheap. I'm trying to get Google Apps to recognize the MX records for my domain, but it appears that since I'm using CNAME'S on my domain that it won't be so easy. Here are the three records I currently have:
[image]

I'm okay with changing the records, but essentially I need to be able to access my site from both anymarket.co and www.anymarket.co. So, my question is, what is the easiest way to change these records so that Google will recognize the MX records for email?

Comment: Where are you trying to route your email?  Are you using a email service, self hosting or trying to route it to your Heroku app?

Comment: I'm trying to host my email on Google Apps for Business

Comment: so the email would be @anymarket.co, and route to Google Apps

Comment: In that case, there is no conflict. Just add the Google MX records to your DNS. Your CNAMEs and redirect can remain in place. Mine are setup  the same way with CNAMEs pointing to Heroku and MX records pointing to Google.

Answer (score -1):

The MX values for Google Apps can be found here

https://support.google.com/a/answer/174125?hl=en

```
Name/Host/Alias     Time to Live (TTL*) Record Type Priority    Value/Answer/Destination
Blank or @          3600                MX          1           ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
Blank or @          3600                MX          5           ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
Blank or @          3600                MX          5           ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
Blank or @          3600                MX          10          ALT3.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
Blank or @          3600                MX          10          ALT4.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
```